# Html.EditFor not finding editor template

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Please help!  This is driving me insane.

I'm trying to refactor some code because there's a bunch of cut-and-paste in the Models, Views and Controller.

**View Model**

```
namespace Foo.Models.Bar
{
[KnownType(typeof(RecruitEditModel))]
public class RecruitEditModel
{
    //...
    public CommonServicesEditModel Services { get; set; }
```

Services is a property that contains another class within the model where I'm putting the common code.

**View in Foo\Views**

```
@model RecruitEditModel
@* ... *@
@using (Html.BeginForm("RecruitEdit", "AppMgmt", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
@* ... *@
@*@Html.Partial("TradeEdit", Model.Services)  <<< DOESN'T BIND *@
 @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Services)  @* BINDS *@
<input type="submit" value="Save" />
}
```

Using a partial on a nested class won't work because the nested class won't bind. (http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2011/09/07/building-forms-for-deep-view-model-graphs-in-asp-net-mvc/)

So I have to use an editor template.

**Editor Template in Foo\Views\Shared\EditorTemplates\TradeEdit.cshtml**

```
@model Services.CommonServicesEditModel
    <div class="left">
        <h3>Howdy</h3>
        <div class="left theTrade">General Contracting:&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.TradeGC)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TradeGC)
    </div>
    @*...*@
```

The problem I'm running into is that apparently the editor template isn't being found and instead a default editor is getting generated.

I found this out while trying to tweak the CSS. The "Howdy" in the header in the EditorTemplate is not being generated.  No matter what I do, short of commenting out the EditFor call there's no change to the displayed fields.

I'm running debugging on local IIS and I've tried restarting the app pool and refreshing the website but no joy.

How do I get changes in the editor template to propagate to the view?

Comment: You have something really messed up here... your context makes no sense... What type is TradeGC?  Your post says the template is called TradeEdit.cshtml, is that getting called?  I don't see a TradeEdit type there.. Your types are totally different from what you're showing...  I also don't see any nested classes here... Services is not a nested class, it's just a property.  Nested classes are classes that are *DEFINED* within other classes... ie `class foo { class bar { ... } }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer was in something obvious but not so obvious.  I thought that the editor template would resolve on the model declaration in the editor template. No, it's easier than that.

The editor template must be named {type}.cshtml.

Another possibility is that I could have used UIHint like this:

```
   [UIHint("TradeEdit")]
   public CommonServicesEditModel Services { get; set; }
```

but I haven't tested that.

Thanks to [Growing With the Web](http://www.growingwiththeweb.com/2012/12/aspnet-mvc-display-and-editor-templates.html) for the answer.

Comment: That's kind of a dichotomy... it would have to know the type to find the type to resolve the type....

Answer (score -1):

In the model 'RecruitEditModel' put the nested class with 'virtual' keyword like this:

```
namespace Foo.Models.Bar
{
[KnownType(typeof(RecruitEditModel))]
public class RecruitEditModel
{
  //...
  public virtual CommonServicesEditModel Services { get; set; }
```

and if u have database you should update it after this :)

Comment: Virtual has nothing whatsoever to do with EditorTemplates

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch it does with Database Schema, if its not virtual it will not be mapped, therefore it will be null if you try to send it to Html helper

Comment: @MartinSolev - there's no indication he's even using a database schema.  In fact, he uses the word "view model" which is typically exactly the opposite.  And still have nothing to do with Editor Templates.